# Parse through XML using Nodelist in a loop

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse through a XML and find the count of elements in a particular tag. My current code is

```
NodeList listEmail = dct.getElementsByTagName("EMAIL");
NodeList listphone = dct.getElementsByTagName("PHONE");
NodeList listaddd = dct.getElementsByTagName("ADDRESS");
NodeList listname = dct.getElementsByTagName("NAME");
totalAssets = listEmail.getLength() + listphone.getLength() + listaddd.getLength() + listname.getLength();
```

The XML i try to parse is. So the output count would be 4 here.

```
<RESPONSE>
    <EMAIL>xxx</EMAIL>
    <PHONE>yyyy</PHONE>
    <ADDRESS>xxxxxx</ADDRESS>
    <NAME>abcd</NAME>
</RESPONSE>
```

I want to make these 4 lines of code to one line using a loop and give the same output which is the count.

Comment: question is not clear. please share the expected output

Comment: The output for the current code will be 4 (count of elements under response tag). similarly,i want to make these four lines where it parse through the elements to one line using a loop and the output should be 4

Answer (score 0):

If you use Java 8 you can try streams:

```
Integer totalAssets = Stream.of("EMAIL", "PHONE", "ADDRESS", "NAME").mapToInt(f-> dct.getElementsByTagName(f).getLength()).sum();
```